# ElasticSearch: Fastest way to score as weighted sum of exponential decays?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am interested in finding the **fastest** solution to the below scoring question in Elasticsearch 2.1

I have in my documents several analogous fields, `weight_1, ..., weight_N` and `decay_1, ..., decay_N`.  I also know, ahead of time, the parameters `decay_1, ..., decay_N` and `scale_1, ..., scale_N`.  I want to have the following computed as the document score:

`SUM(weight_i * 0.5**((decay_i - origin_i) / scale_i), i=1..N)`

I will know `N` ahead of time -- so I will know exactly how many fields need to be summed and the scoring solution does not need to handle a dynamic number of fields.

This is very easy to do with `N = 1`:

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "exp": {
                  "decay_1": {
                     "origin": "origin_1",
                     "scale": "scale_1",
                     "decay": "0.5"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "weight_1",
                  "missing": 0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Certainly I can accomplish this with Lucene expressions (since I know `N` ahead of time) or with a native Java script or Groovy script.  But I'm interested in the **most performant** solution, which seems to typically mean using builtins wherever possible.